# How to check if specific web browser is installed on system?

Tags: c++, windows, firefox, google-chrome, registry

How to check if specific web browser (chrome, firefox, opera) is installed on system? (C++/Windows platform). Maybe this can be check in somewhere in registry?

Comment: windows registry check might be good enough for your needs; but keep in mind that there might still be something like Firefox Portable with no trace in registry.

Answer (score 3):

Like Andrey says, there is no way to detect everything

You should probably start off by looking for browser specific registry keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Opera Software
```

then move on to

```
<HKEY_CURRENT_USER|HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet
```

and finally

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\HTTP and HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.htm[l]
```